# ts-node runs tests on OS X but not in Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, mocha.js, ts-node

I'm having a strange issue with TS-Error being thrown when I run my tests in Linux but running fine and passing in OS X.

The project is written in Typescript and tested with Mocha (using ts-node). When I run the tests on OS X I don't experience any issues, but as soon as I try and run them on a linux box, they fail, giving the error:

error TS6054: File '/[user]/workspace/content-delivery-application/templates/footer.html.twig' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts', '.js', '.jsx'

I do include Twig files in the source code, which are bundled as part of the Webpack build process, and I wrap them in try catches and return a stub function in the place of the template. However the test code is run on the precompiled TS files through TS Node, hence the Files have not been packed. Although I want to stress, the 'workaround' try catch has been working in my OS X.

My Mocha opts looks like this:

```
--require ts-node/register
--require source-map-support/register
--full-trace
--recursive
--timeout 10000
test/**/*.spec.ts
```

And my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": [                                  /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
      "es5",
      "es2015.promise",
      "es2017"
    ],
     "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
     "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": false,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": false,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    //"strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
     //"strictFunctionTypes": false,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    //"noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    //"noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    //"noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
     "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "exclude": [
      "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "types": [ "typePatches" ]
}
```

And the culprit function:

```
public static requireFooter(): any {
        try {
            // needs to be a string literal as requires are calculated on build not at runtime
            return require('../../templates/footer.html.twig');
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.error("[TSError] footer.html.twig is an unsupported extension. <p>data</p> is returned as workaround.");
            return function(data) {
                return "<p>data</p>";
            }
        }     
    }
```

I Appreciate this is a lot of text, so thank you for reading. Please let me know if you have any thoughts as to what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

> error TS6054: File '/[user]/workspace/content-delivery-application/templates/footer.html.twig' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts', '.js', '.jsx'

This is a TypeScript *compile time* error. The same version of TypeScript on different OSes *should* give the same result. Therefore your TypeScript versions are different on mac vs. ubuntu. Make them consistent and you will have a consistent *error* (or *no error*) experience.